# Ruby: different values of self inside lambda when using instance_eval(&lambda) vs instance_eval { lambda.call }

Tags: ruby

I want to call a lambda changing it's self value. Searching for it, I arrived at `instance_exec`, which was supposed to get the job done.

However, after 1+ hour studying an example, I found this behavior I can't explain:

```rb
class Dummy

  class << self

    attr_accessor :my_lambda

  end

  self.my_lambda = proc { self }

  def test
    self.class.my_lambda.call
  end

  def test1
    instance_eval(&self.class.my_lambda)
  end

  def test2
    instance_eval { self.class.my_lambda.call }
  end

end

Dummy.new.test
=> Dummy # I was expecting this, returns the class, lexical scope (where `self` was defined)

Dummy.new.test1
=> #<Dummy:0x00007fe982f8b678> # I was expecting this, `self` changed to the receiver of `instance_eval`, which is the instance, so `self` returned the instance.

Dummy.new.test2
=> Dummy # I can't understand this, at all. Why isn't it the same as test1?
```

So, why do we get different results from `instance_eval(&self.class.my_lambda)` vs `instance_eval { self.class.my_lambda.call }` ?

Also, since we're at the subject of calling Lambdas ... if I change the class level variable to this:

```
self.my_lambda = lambda { self }
```

then Dummy.new.test1 throws an exception `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`, which I also can't understand why, since I know lambdas are strict about argument numbers, but we didn't pass any when we used `instance_eval(&self.class.my_lambda)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland no it's not. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly how, right away after writing this long question, I managed to answer it myself in one extra minute. I needed a rubber duck. Anyways.

I misunderstood `instance_eval`. It "Executes the given block within the context of the receiver (obj)."

So, the given block in `#test2` `instance_eval { self.class.my_lambda.call }` was, indeed, executed with `self` set to the instance, *but* the lambda was still called within it, which doesn't change *it's* self.

However, in `#test1`, the ampersand `&` changed the proc to a block, and then it was passed to `instance_eval`, so it was the proc's own body that was executed with the `self` changed.

Comment: Nailed it. `&` in an argument list "unrolls" the given `Proc` into a block as-if it had been written as a literal block argument. Likewise, `&` in a parameter list does the opposite: it "packages" the block in to `Proc` object.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thank you for the comment. Do you know why the `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` if I use `lambda` ?

Comment: As [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) says: "When `instance_eval` is given a block, *obj* is also passed in as the block’s only argument." So, `instance_eval` passes `self` as an argument to the block, and when you "unroll" a `Proc` into a block, it keeps its strict/loose parameter checking behavior. IOW, a block created by unrolling a lambda will not check its parameters like a block but like a lambda. You defined your lambda to take no parameters, but `instance_eval` is passing one argument.